# How to trigger a windows application form created using visual studio when the power mode is changed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, visual-studio-2012, event-handling

Am a novice in programming and am developing an app using visual studio(c#) that tells me the time the system has run on battery when the AC power plug has connected.I used System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PowerStatus.PowerLineStatus to check whether system is running on battery or AC power.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event handler `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged`

In the event just check for if the `e.Mode == PowerModes.StatusChange` and what the status is and do what you want for that status. Launch your form, or whatever you intend to do for the met criteria.

EDIT: The above would need to be in an application (System Tray or something) that runs at startup. It would be mostly there to hook into that event and perform whatever tasks you need when the event is fired.